# how to compensate gravity in gazebo?

Tags: ros, pid, microcontroller, gazebo, joint

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
I have set PID controllers in gazebo, now I want to add the gravity compensation. what should I do?
actually i want to add offset to the output of PID controllers.
is there any topic that i can publish to it ?
i'm working on a industrial robot that have 5 joints + gantry ( visual servo ) .

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203971/how-to-compensate-gravity-in-gazebo-?/) by [babaksn](https://answers.ros.org/users/21552/babaksn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2015-02-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe there is no ready-made controller providing PID control with feedforward gravity compensation. You could look into modifying the PID approach you are already using (custom gazebo plugin? gazebo_ros_control?) and adding gravity compensation.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2015-02-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) on 2015-03-02**:
I would add it either to your 'robot driver', or as a separate controller that runs in parallel to the PID. I'd avoid trying to extend the PID implementation, as gravity compensation is model-based, whereas a plain PID is not. More details on your approach would help, as Stefan points out.